# Chebyshev's inequality bound

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider 50,000 independent tosses of a fair coin and consider S as the number of heads obtained in them.What is the lower bound as deduced strictly by the Chebyshev's inequality for the probability that $S\over 1000$ differs from $1\over2$ by less than $0.2.$
I first calculated the variance of $S\over1000$ and used it in the Chebyshev's inequality and got the answer as 0.999875. Is it correct? If not please can someone explain it would be of great help

Comment: What formula do you have for Chebyshev's inequality? The one I know gives an upper bound, not a lower one, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: I think the chebyshevs inequality gives the upper bound when $|X-u|>k\sigma$ so we calculate $1-P(|X-u|<k\sigma)< 1/k^2$

Comment: Oh, I think I misread the question. Yes, that's what I was thinking. If you did that, then I think it should work.

Comment: Also, don't just describe what you did. You should type it out. You might get a response sooner, since others won't guess what's happening. Use `$\mu$` to show $\mu$.

Comment: I just wanted to know that the $\sigma$ that we have would be of $S\over 1000$ instead of $\sigma$ of S???

Comment: If you want to use $S/1000$, then you need the sd of $S/1000$, not $S$.